# How to match exact word in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I want to get the data from mariadb on a specific column to match the specific word in that column and give me all the rows that math the word. For example I want to match the word "was". I am trying too much but not
found any regular expression that find the exact word.
Help me...

When I write query I give me all rows in which the word "was" is alone or appended in some string. But I
want only those rows in word "was" is a complete word not appended with some string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [MariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regular-expressions-overview/#word-boundaries) you have to use word boundaries

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

```
SELECT column1, column2, .. FROM yourtable 
  WHERE was_column REGEXP "[[:<:]]was[[:>:]]"
```